# question about meaning of と言われては in this tweet

Tags: grammar, て-form, particle-は

> そんなに特殊なあれこれはしていないと思うのだけど……。「誰かがこのサイトを偽装しようとしています」と言われては、背景を調べずにokを押すわけにもいかない。こんなことをしている場合ではないのに。

Im don’t understand the meaning to this part : `と言われては`  
 This might be an answered question but I couldn’t find anything about it and my best guess was it being a case of omitted いけない at first but it doesn’t seem to work here very well? besides I think that structure could only be used with negative verbs? 
 I’d be very happy if you could provide me with some hint in regards to the function of the said part that could help me understand the meaning as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ては/では(/ちゃ/じゃ) is a "conditional" expression that is translated either as *if* or *because/when*. (Calling the latter "conditional" may seem counterintuitive, but it is often useful to think they belong to one spectrum in Japanese. [ば](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72216/5010) is another example of this.) In your case, 言われて is something that has already happened, to this ては is an emphatic "because". It can be translated using "Now that ～", too.

- ～と言われては、背景を調べずにOKを押すわけにもいかない。
  Now that I was told ～, I cannot press OK without checking the background.
- こうなっては仕方がない。
  Now that things have come to this, I have no choice (but to do this). [before playing the final card]
- そんなに泣かれちゃ、私も優しくしたくなるよ。
  If/Since you cry like that, I will want to be gentle to you.

It is often followed by undesirable consequences, as seen above.

> #### [ては](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF/)
>
> ２ 反駁 (はんぱく) ・感心などの強い感情をもたらす原因となる条件を示す。…たからには。「そこまで言われては黙っていられない」「これだけやっつけられては反論する気も起きない」